# custom textboxes changed location for windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, custom-controls

I made windows form application in win 7 .net 3.5, all the custom textboxes were give hardcoded locations everything went well in all xp systems, & even in win 7 systems which had .net 4(Client Profile only) but for windows 7 system with .net 4.0(client profile & extended) all the custom textboxes are to the above and left of their labels showing a pattern as if they were not anchored with the form.

But when i resize the form in .net 3.5 the textboxes & labels do not move because they are not anchored in their locations as expected.

Any ideas whats happening?

[image]

`Edit 1:` I just tried the program on a system with .Net 4 Client Profile & Extended and it worked fine, so there is definetly wrong in the system where above image was taken, Perhaps some screen resolution issue?

Comment: @ColeJohnson updated question & posted pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/facepalm Sorry guys, my bad the windows font on the system was set to medium, my application was expecting it to be small.